# Banner changer issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the lines of code  for a banner changer and whenever i add a link to any of the banners, it goes blank "The banner space goes blank." every now and then.

```
         $(function(){

        $('#banner img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){$('#banner :first-

            child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#banner');}, 8000);
            });


     </script>
```

```
       <div id="banner">


           <img src="images/hollinger.png" width="519" height="76" />
           <img src="banners/leonards.png" width="519" height="76" />
           <img  src="banners/banner1.png" width="493" height="82" border="0" />


       </div><!-- End Banner -

->
```

Here's the link to unstand what I mean Here's the link to understand what I mean http://woodstown-pilesgrove.com/

Comment: What exactly "goes blank"? Can you please explain it better?

Comment: Here's the link to understand what I mean http://woodstown-pilesgrove.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes blank because there is a `<a>` link within the banner.

```
<div id="banner">
  <img src="images/hollinger.png" width="519" height="76" />
  <img src="banners/leonards.png" width="519" height="76" />
  <a href="index.html"><img  src="banners/banner1.png" width="493" height="82" border="0" /></a>
</div>
```

So when the last image gets appended to the banner, it is no longer wrapped by the link, so you end up with this (only the link showing and thus a blank banner):

```
<div id="banner">
  <a href="index.html"></a>
  <img style="display:none;" src="images/hollinger.png" width="519" height="76" />
  <img style="display:none;" src="banners/leonards.png" width="519" height="76" />
  <img style="display:none;" src="banners/banner1.png" width="493" height="82" border="0" />
</div>
```

Try removing the link. But if you really need a link, change `<div id="banner">` into `<a id="banner" href="http://whatever.com">`.